# Flutter, break out private method to a helper class. Arguments problem

Tags: flutter, dart, private, public

I would like to break out this method and make it public in a helper class but I run into this error when trying and passing context to it? It wants two required contexts and `BuildContext` but I don't know how to implement this? I get this error. It seems to be a problem with two context arguments also:

"2 positional arguments required but found 0. Try to add missing arguments"

Or if I type the first context it is:

"1 positional argument required but found 0. Try to add missing arguments"

Private method:

```dart
_showDialog() {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Title'),
        content: Text('Body'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          OutlinedButton(
            child: Text('Close'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Public method (with two context arguments):

```dart
class _LegendScreenState extends State<LegendScreen> {
  showDialog(context, BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Title'),
          content: Text('Body'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            OutlinedButton(
              child: Text('Close'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is coming because, you are defining [`showDialog`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html) method that is already defined on `material.dart`. It is overlapping with name. Try to rename the helper class something else like `appDialog` and pass `context`.

```dart
  appDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
```

More about [`showDialog`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html)

Comment: Thank you Yeasin! Sometimes you can stare yourself blind on somethings :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove one context argument. You only need one.

```
showDialog(context, BuildContext context) {
```

should be:

```
showDialog(BuildContext context) {
```

Comment: I guess its the same context anyhow :) Unfortunatly still error: 1 expected but found 0.

Comment: Well, how do you call it?